# Find the longest subsequence containing as many 1 as 0 time O(n)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, count, sequence

I had a question in an interview and I couldn't find the optimal solution (and it's quite frustrating lol)

So you have a n-list of 1 and 0.
110000110101110..
The goal is to extract the longest sub sequence containing as many 1 as 0.
Here for example it is "110000110101" or "100001101011" or "0000110101110"

I have an idea for O(n^2), just scanning all possibilities from the beginning to the end, but apparently there is a way to do it in O(n).
Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you mean the longest substring (i.e., the element must be consecutive (adjacent))? In general, subsequence allows gaps e.g., `[1, 3]` is a subsequence of `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: Subsequence would be trivial. Simply take the whole sequence and remove excess 0s / 1s.

Comment: @PiotrDabkowski: yes. That is why I've asked (because I think that OP meant `substring`).

Answer (score 7):

Consider `'10110'`:

1. Create a variable `S`. Create array `A=[0]`.
2. Iterate from first number and add 1 to S if you notice 1 and subtract 1 from S if you notice 0 and append `S` to `A`.

   - For our example sequence `A` will be: `[0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1]`. `A` is simply an array which stores a difference between number of 1s and 0s preceding the index. The sequence has to start and end at the place which has the same difference between 1s and 0s. So now our task is to find the longest distance between same numbers in `A`.
3. Now create 2 empty dictionaries (hash maps) `First` and `Last`.
4. Iterate through `A` and save position of first occurrence of every number in `A` in dictionary `First`.
5. Iterate through `A` (starting from the end) and save position of the last occurrence of each number in `A` in dictionary `Last`.

   - So for our example array First will be `{0:0, 1:1, 2:4}` and Last will be `{0:2, 1:5, 2:4}`
6. Now find the key(`max_key`) for which the difference between corresponding values in `First` and `Last` is the largest. This max difference is the length of the subsequence. Subsequence starts at `First[max_key]` and ends at `Last[max_key]`.

I know it is a bit hard to understand but it has complexity O(n) - four loops, each has complexity N. You can replace dictionaries with arrays of course but it is more complicated then using dictionaries.

Solution in Python.

```py
def find_subsequence(seq):
    S = 0
    A = [0]
    for e in seq:
        if e=='1':
            S+=1
        else:
            S-=1
        A.append(S)
    First = {}
    Last = {}
    for pos, e in enumerate(A):
        if e not in First:
            First[e] = pos
    for pos, e in enumerate(reversed(A)):
        if e not in Last:
            Last[e] = len(seq) - pos
    max_difference = 0
    max_key = None
    for key in First:
        difference = Last[key] - First[key]
        if difference>max_difference:
            max_difference = difference
            max_key  = key
    if max_key is None:
        return ''
    return seq[First[max_key]:Last[max_key]]

find_sequene('10110') # Gives '0110'
find_sequence('1') # gives ''
```

[J.F. Sebastian's code](http://ideone.com/d8cZTH) is more optimised.

---

**EXTRA**

This problem is related to [Maximum subarray problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem). Its solution is also based on summing elements from start:

```
def max_subarray(arr):
    max_diff = total = min_total = start = tstart = end = 0
    for pos, val in enumerate(arr, 1):
        total += val
        if min_total > total:
            min_total = total
            tstart =  pos
        if total - min_total > max_diff:
            max_diff = total - min_total
            end = pos
            start = tstart
    return max_diff, arr[start:end]
```

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Your code is much better. I tried to keep things simple and easy to understand :) By the way how long did it take you to write this code?

Comment: `git log` says more than hour between the initial commit (the code from the answer) and the final version. I've tried to come up with something like [Kadane's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) to make it a single pass, constant memory algorithm but failed.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian you managed to make it single pass. I dont think it is possible to make it constant memory. In Kadane's algorithm you are looking for the greatest difference between values. And here you are looking for the greatest distance between same values.